# Get the GPS coordinates of a photo in Mac Photos.app

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, photos.app, gps

In Mac's Photos.app, how do I get the GPS coordinates of a photo? If I go to a photo and click on the "Get Info" button, then I can see a map with a pin indicating where the photo was taken, but I can't find out how to get the actual GPS coordinates (latitude and longitude) from this.

Also, when exporting photos from Photos.app, the GPS information is removed, so I can't even use other apps or even just Preview.app to get this info.

Comment: You can however set Apple Photos to include location information in exported images. There are two separate settings. One in Preferences and one in the export window. See https://blog.houdah.com/2015/12/keeping-geotags-dragging-images-apple-photos/ for screenshots.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just tested exporting a file from Photos and it retained GPS information. Are you using Export > Export X Photo(s), or Export > Export Unmodified Originals for X Photo(s)? I used the latter.

To find the actual GPS coordinates there are many, many solutions, but I used the most-excellent command line [ExifTool](http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) when testing to ensure the GPS information was still present after export.

```
$ exiftool -gpslatitude -gpslongitude ~/Desktop/IMG_9337.jpg
GPS Latitude                    : 41 deg 2' 14.99" N
GPS Longitude                   : 90 deg 8' 38.55" W
```

There are many things you can do with this, including scanning an entire directory and outputting their GPS coords to a file, outputting into HTML format, etc. The above command will give you a basic display of it, though.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the photo and choose edit with Preview. Go to `Tools → Show location info` and click on the GPS tag.

Comment: doesn't work. It's greyed out

Answer (score 0):

on last OS you have, even in JPEG:

[image]

You will have in Finder:
[image]